# React state is not updating when react-router-dom Link is used with material ui ListItem onClick

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom

I have a drawer component where I put my List items in a List, on each List item click I'm navigating to respective page. I'm able to do this successfully but when I want to update state on each list item click, it is not updating on single click. I want to update my state with respective index. If I remove component & to props in ListItem, updating state is working fine. Can someone please help me in this.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

const handleListItemClick = (event, index) => {
    setValue(index);
}

<ListItem
            button
            selected={selected}
            onClick={event => handleListItemClick(event, 0)}
            component={Link}
            to={"/home"}
          >
<ListItem
            button
            selected={selected}
            onClick={event => handleListItemClick(event, 1)}
            component={Link}
            to={"/some-page"}
          >
```

Comment: Have you checked that `Link` isn't absorbing your `onClick` event? does `console.log` work if you make that the `onClick` action?

Comment: Console.log of state after updating? if I console.log the index value from my handleListItemClick function I can see proper index value of list item but when I set that to a state variable its not updating. Not just updating state, if I assign the index value from `handleListItemClick` to any variable still its not reflecting. All I see is old value. but when I click 2 times I see state is getting udpated @Garr

Comment: I tried using `withRouter` & `history.push`, still I see state is not getting updated but when I remove `history.push` state is updating properly @GarrettMotzner

Comment: @Ravi please try to create a working example to show the issue you are facing. You can use https://codesandbox.io for that.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to replicate the issue in codesandbox. I see issue only in my app, may be some issue in using `routes` or `Link` @Dekel